# Sphinx attribute not found

Tags: sphinx

I get why this generally happens but I'm sort of facing an (apparent) mystery here.

In my  `sql_query = SELECT` in my `Sphinx` configuration file, I have a # of `LEFT Joins`.  Afterward, I declare some of these as attributes, some as `sql_attr_uint` some as `sql_attr_string`. This has all worked fine until now.

I recently added a single value to the select, call it `i.Color` and then added the attribute, `sql_attr_string = Color`

When I rotate I get the error `WARNING. Sphinx Attribute Color not found`.

This led me to believe there was an issue with the joins so I pulled the entire select into `Navicat` and ran it there and it returns the value find (being a `LEFT JOIN` some records it found a value for, others were NULL).

Any recommendations on what else to check? I know this is somewhat vague yet posting the entire super complex config here won't clarify at all believe me :)

Comment: can you show the whole SELECT query?

Comment: @ManticoreSearch It is kind of massive, let me try to simplify it to the core selects/tables. Again when I copy it into Navicat and run it I get the field I asked for.

Comment: run  indexer with --print-queries  and dump the  full statement.